# How can I replace label text with css ( without id )

Tags: css, replace

I Have a simple code:

```
<div class="delem"><label class="required" for="last_name">Full Name :</label><input id="fullname" type="text" name="fullname" value="" class="fullsize" required=""></div>



<div class="delem"><label class="required" for="identity_number">Personal ID Number:</label><input id="identity_number" type="text" name="_identityNumber" value="" class="fullsize" required=""></div>
```

i want change the "Personal ID Number" with css.

Comment: what's your beef with ids? Ids are a great way to select individual elements.. but if you're hell bend.. `$('div.delem').closest('label')` should get the first instance of the label

Comment: Please write the complete question in the big box, rather than scattering it in comments. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately i can't access the main page to change it, But I can integrate the CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the font size of the label to 0, to hide the text. Put the new text for the label in the ::before or ::after pseudo-element, and set its font size to what the label's size was originally. (Assuming 1rem here.)

```css
label[for="identity_number"] {
  font-size: 0
}

label[for="identity_number"]::after {
  font-size: 1rem;
  content: 'Some other number: ';
}
```

```html
<div class="delem"><label class="required" for="identity_number">Personal ID Number:</label><input id="identity_number" type="text" name="_identityNumber" value="" class="fullsize" required=""></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.delem:nth-child(2) label {
    position:relative}
.delem:nth-child(2) label::before {
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
    width:136px;
    height:21px;
    content:"Place your Text:"}
```